# how to immediately use the result of computation in another computation within MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, select

so I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(x) AS s, s + 600 AS y FROM table;
```

But then mysql complained...unknown column 's' in 'field list' which I suppose comes from s + 600 expression....

how do I format the query such that I can immediately use the SUM(x) computation alias 's' in the computation that immediately follows it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT s, s + 600 AS y FROM (SELECT SUM(x) AS s FROM table);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(x) AS s, SUM(x) + 600 AS y FROM table;
```

You cannot re-use aliases in the select list; it's not like "variable declaration" in programming languages.

SQL Statements are executed in the following order:

1. FROM (join source tables)
2. WHERE (filter result set)
3. GROUP BY (group data)
4. HAVING (filter resulting groups)
5. SELECT (select/calculate result columns)
6. ORDER BY (sort data)

This means you can use aliases from SELECT in the ORDER BY, and nowhere else.

Comment: without rewriting the actual expression since my actual query is actually much more complicated

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot As I said: *You can't*. Just copy the expression, the DB server will do the necessary caching if it is any good at its job. Alternatively create a sub-select like Yahia suggests.

Comment: if I do that will it actually recompute SUM(x)...so SUM(x) gets executed twice...

Comment: @kamikaze: Are you *sure* or do you suspect this? Have you tried and measured execution times?

Answer (score 0):

Why generate the second column in MySQL? Just create the second part in PHP; that way you can spend less time in your shared resource (the database server) and move the rest of the time to what is generally your scalable resource (your web servers).

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_id);
$row['y'] = $row['s'] + 600;
```

The only real reason I could see for really wanting to create the second column is if this query is part of a subexpression within a larger query (e.g. you're generating bounds for another query or some such).